# Integrating PHPUnit with CakePHP 1.3

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-1.3

I have been looking for a tutorial to help me integrate PHPUnit with CakePHP. Looking to use Selenium tests too so prefer PHPUnit.

I have been trying to follow the tutorial on http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2006/03/22/selenium/ but cant seem to get it work. Any good tutorials out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately CakePHP isn't designed to work together with PHPUnit. CakePHP has switched to using [SimpleTest](http://simpletest.sourceforge.net/) and you'll have one of two choices, refactor your tests to work with SimpleTest or modify the core to use PHPUnit.

However it should be stated that [Mark Story has stated that CakePHP 2.0 will use PHPUnit](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/cakephp-and-phpunit) for it's testing framework, so if you can aford to wait till then that may wind up being the best option.

[CakePHP 1.3 Book on Testing](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Testing.html)

Comment: Thanks! I have no tests at the moment thats why I can still choose between the two. I'll spent some time trying to see if I can get CakePHP to use PHPUnit core instead.

Comment: SimpleTest is always problematic, especially with test data for models.

Comment: I'd like to modify my 1.3 core to use PHPUnit. Any clues how to make this happen?

Answer (score 5):

It's relatively easy. I use cake 1.3 from composer installation. This is how my composer.json looks like:

```
{
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "vendors/composer"
    },
    "require": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*",
        "cakephp/cakephp-1.3": "1.3",
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "cakephp/cakephp-1.3",
                "version": "1.3",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "1.3"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Then the phpunit bootstrap.php file in tests directory:

```
<?php
include('../vendors/composer/autoload.php');
include('../webroot/index.php');
```

This is phpunit.xml form the same dir:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
     bootstrap="bootstrap.php"

     backupStaticAttributes="false"

     cacheTokens="false"
     colors="false"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     forceCoversAnnotation="false"
     mapTestClassNameToCoveredClassName="false"
     printerClass="PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter"

     processIsolation="false"
     stopOnError="false"
     stopOnFailure="false"
     stopOnIncomplete="false"
     stopOnSkipped="false"
     testSuiteLoaderClass="PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader"

     strict="false"
     verbose="false"
    >

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="AllTests">
        <directory>.</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <blacklist>
            <directory suffix=".php"></directory>
            <file></file>
            <exclude>
                <directory suffix=".php"></directory>
                <file></file>
            </exclude>
        </blacklist>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php"></directory>
            <file></file>
            <exclude>
                <directory suffix=".php"></directory>
                <file></file>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

Don't forget to load your application classes in test setup. You can do it cakephp way. For example if your controller is named calendar your calendarTest.php may look like:

```
<?php

/**
 * Class ComponentsCommonTest
 * @property calendarController $calendarController
 */
class CalendarTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var calendarController $calendarController
     */
    private $calendarController;

    function setUp()
    {
        App::import('Core', array('View', 'Controller', 'Model', 'Router'));
        App::import('Controller', 'Calendar');
        $this->calendarController =& new CalendarController();
        $this->calendarController->constructClasses();
        $this->calendarController->layout = null;
    }
}
```

The same for models, vendor classes and so on. Works great for me.